# How to assess predictive power of each predictor in case of linear regression

Tags: regression

For a predictive model with binary target, we can assess the predictive power of each predictor by calculating their information value. What is the equivalent of IV when the target variable is continuous? Should I look at $R^2$ value of individual predictor when used as a sole predictor in a regression model?

Edited:
I have 4300 attributes to choose from. So adding all attributes would be impossible. I want to sort the attributes based on their individual predictive power and add a short list of 50 attributes to my model.

Comment: Why not consider model's parameters? I don't think I understood your question, but if I did, your model's parameters will let you know exactly the contribution of each predictor to final's output.

Comment: Hi Victor, thanks. I have updated my original questions. I have 4000+ attributes to choose from. That is why I want to reduce the list based on the individual power of the attributes.

Comment: Why not include all 4000 variables? [Variable selection is actually quite unstable.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18245/247274)

Comment: HI Dave, adding all variables can be inefficient as they are all correlated to some of the other variables. The PCA analysis will reduce the number of variables to <15 dimensions. Plus storage cost of all the variables over millions of rows can be expensive in terms of storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: If you do need to do feature selection then yes you would use R^2. Look up forward and backward feature selection. Another good option is to use L1 regularization. I would probably try L1 first if you're able to run the model with all the features. I am guessing you wont want to do L1 regularization or backward selection because you are trying to avoid running the regression with all variables? If that is the case I would recommend using forward selection and just stop at whatever num variables you want your model to end up having. It is better to do forward selection than simply finding R^2 for every X with the outcome.

---

It sounds like your question is about how to interpret your model. However when I read the comments, it seems like you are asking about how to reduce the number of variables for the model.

Based on assuming that you are trying to ask about using less variables. The next question I would ask is what is the goal for reducing the number of attributes? If it is for regularization (to prevent overfitting) then the person that commented about variable selection being unstable is correct. You can do cross validation with L1 or L2 regularization, or both (elastic net). Furthermore, if you do L1 regularization, you can also use this as another way to do feature selection because it will assign coefficients to the variables with 0 or 1.

If you are trying to reduce the number of variables because you want to reduce computational complexity to reduce training time or use less memory then you can do feature selection or dimensionality reduction. If you do feature selection you are picking the features that have the best predictive power. There are different ways to do feature selection (ex: forward selection, backward selection). You can also do dimensionality reduction (ex: PCA) which will create "new features" AKA principal components out of the original features which are linear combinations of the original features. These principal components do not have anything to do with the outcome variable (unlike feature selection and regularization). The top principal components are the combos of the original features that provide the most information.

Comment: Regarding your first sentence about forward and backward feature selection, [“Stepwise regression model-building is…pants.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/156093/247274) -Dr. Alexis Dinno

Comment: @Dave Not sure I understand your comment....

Comment: As is discussed in the link, “Stepwise regression model-building is garbage, malarkey, hooey, poppycock… it's just pants.” (“Pants” is slang in the UK meaning that something is of low quality.)

Comment: I see. Well forward / backward selection isn't stepwise regression. but even aside from that, its important to try to answer the question that the poster is asking even if you disagree with it. Additionally, there are reasons to do feature selection before running a model. Some people don't have access to AWS or GCP or whatever where they can run models as complex and as as with much data as they like. Your response is kind of rude. If you read my full post you will see that I agreed with you and said that you should not do feature selection in this way unless you have to